# How to create empty dataframe if file is not available in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading file and then creating a temporary view using pyspark but I want to know if file is not available then it create empty dataframe.

I am using below code:

```
df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\001').options(header='true',inferSchema='false').load(row['Source File Name Lnd'])

df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView(row['landingdfname'])
```

Temporaray view name - `vw_case`

But suppose if file is not available in Source File Name Lnd then will it create empty dataframe?

What will be result of below code?

```
spark.sql("Select * from vw_case").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file won't exist under the specified location `row['Source File Name Lnd']` then the loading function will return an error. You can't load non-existing files so you wouldn't even get to the code you are asking about.

The easiest way to solve for missing files is to check if they exist before loading and either ignore the missing file or create an empty dataframe for that missing file. Something like this could help:

```
if len(dbutils.fs.ls(row['Source File Name Lnd'])) > 0:
    df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\001').options(header='true',inferSchema='false').load(row['Source File Name Lnd'])
else:
    df_read_file = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), StructType([]))

df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView(row['landingdfname'])
```